# get array value in another array php foreach

Tags: php, arrays

i have an array

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [folding_knives__no_assist__possession19] => G
            [folding_knives__no_assist__possession___length20] => 
            [folding_knives__no_assist___open_cary21] => G
            [folding_knives__no_assist__open_carry_length22] => 
            [folding_knives__no_assist__concealed23] => G
            [folding_knives__no_assisted__concealed_length24] => 
            [folding_knives__no_assist__concealed_w__ccw_required25] => R
            [folding_knives__no_assist__concealed_w__ccw_required_l26] => 
            [folding_knives__no_assist___notes27] => 
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [folding_knives__assisted_opening__possession28] => G
            [folding_knives__assisted_opening__possession_length29] => 
            [folding_knives__assisted_opening__open_carry30] => G
            [folding_knives__assisted_opening__open_carry_length31] => 
            [folding_knives__assisted_opening___concealed32] => G
            [folding_knives__assisted_opening__concealed_length33] => 
            [folding_knives__assisted_opening___concealed_w__ccw_re34] => R
            [folding_knives__assisted_opening__concealed_w__ccw_req35] => 
            [folding_knives___assisted_opening___notes36] => 
        )
)
```

I already trying to show my array data into another array but cant

```
foreach ($chunks as $key => $val)
{

                $allknife[] = array( 
                        'name'=>$key[0],
                        'possession'=>$val[0],
                        'possession_length'=>$val[1]                    
                    );


}
```

Here `name'=>$key[0]` here will be arry first item key like folding_knives__no_assist__possession19

Comment: No, Key in this example will be 0, 1, 2...

Comment: now how can i solve this @matiit

Comment: make an other foreach ^^ your key will be "folding_knives__no_assist__possession19" but don't use index or your key will be "f"

Answer (score 0):

It should be link this, and you want field count link 1/2/3/4... then you have to use flag logic like, i=0; and i++

```
$allknife[] = array();
foreach ($chunks as $key => $val)
{
   $allknife['name']=>$val['yourvaluesoeshere'],
   $allknife['possession']=>$val['yourvaluesoeshere'],
   $allknife['possession_length']=>$val['yourvaluesoeshere']                    
}
```

Answer (score -1):

**Since your arrays have inconsistent key names you can't rely on this an need consistent names first!**

Map the array more like this:

```
array(
    0 => array(
        'assist' => true,
        'open_carry_nr' => 21,
        'open_carry_length' => 22
        // and so on...
    ),

    2 => array(
        'assist' => false,
        'open_carry_nr' => 18,
        'open_carry_length' => 1337
        // and so on...
    )
);
```

Way better practice.

Comment: this is wrong $key['folding_knives__no_assist__possession19'] does not exist

Comment: Yep, inconsistent key names have to be avoided in this scenario.